# Why class SecurityEvaluationContextExtension can not be found in Spring Boot Project?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a spring boot based project with following declaration in pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and following dependencies among others

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But seems like spring boot is not pulling in `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` class on the classpath.

Am I missing a dependency or am I using an older version of spring boot?

**EDIT:**

I directly added the following dependency in my pom.xml and now I can see the class, but STS is showing warning : "Duplicating managed version 4.0.3.RELEASE for spring-security-data"

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not shure what you mean with 'spring is not pulling in..'
But to use this extension you have to create a bean of this type see
[SecurityEvaluationContextExtension](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/data/repository/query/SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.html)

EDIT :
The warning you are getting is no problem. You can try removing the version from the dependency, because it seems available through dependencyManagement.

Comment: By pulling in I meant that when we add a maven dependency like `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` it brings in other dependencies. [See this, for example](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom). I have now edited the question and mentioned that the class is missing from the classpath.

Comment: Directly added `spring-security-data` in pom.xml, the issue is resolved but getting a warning. See updated question